# How do you "unpack" a query that queries views in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose that I have a view in BigQuery, e.g. [views.myview] defined as follows:

```
SELECT
  Id AS Id,
  MAX(Time) AS MostRecentTime
FROM
  [dataset.mytable]
GROUP BY
  Id
```

And then another query that queries that view:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [dataset.mytable] tbl
  JOIN [views.myview] view ON tbl.Time = mview.MostRecentTime
```

Is there a way to automatically generate a query where the [views.myview] in the second query is replaced with the query that generates it - basically "unpacking" the views so you have just one query that queries tables directly?

(The underlying problem: I have a query which queries many different views, including several layers of views-querying-other-views, and I want to put this query in my application. I don't want a user to be able to mess with the results of the query by changing the definition of one of the views, so I want to put the whole query in a fixed form in the application.)

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: it is very much depends on context of this question. Conceptually, if you have text of query - it is doable with a little efforts and using the client of your choice. Have you tried something? what was the problem? if you ask more specific question you have better chance to get help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do 'automatically'. You could try writing some script or code to do this through the BigQuery apis - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-views